# Setting the direction of PCA953X I2C GPIO expander pins in the device tree

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio

I've into an interesting problem that I'm hoping someone can help we with. I'm trying to bring up a board which utilises a PCA9537 I2C GPIO Expander chip to control the reset pins of various ICs on the board including items like the ethernet phy.

I've added a device tree node for the PCA device to the device tree and pointed the `reset-gpios` property of the respective devices to the PCA device and its correct IO pin and polarity. Everything compiles and loads. However, I'm getting timeouts on some devices including the Phy. Closer inspection appears to show that the PCA devices IO pins are being left set in their default state of inputs not outputs, and thus some devices are remaining disabled.

Does anybody know how I can change this from within the device tree?

I've looked through the bindings for the device, and nothing has jumped out

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-pca95xx.yaml

Neither has it from the default GPIO bindings

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt

The only thing I can think of is using pictrl but I can't find any binding for the pca953X device pinctrl node even though it's referenced in the binding. I'm therefore wondering if this is because of a cut and paste error and the PCA device doesn't use pinctrl?

I've tried using a `gpio-hog` node but this caused other problems in that although the GPIO pin goes to the required value it prevents other devices accessing the pin so drivers are returning -16 (EBUSY). If I remove their `reset-gpios` property I get a race condition where they try to load before the GPIO and thus the reset is still floating at that point in time.

Comment: Yes, each GPIO _consumer_ shall ask the driver to set certain flags. I.o.w. show your DTs.